# MySQL backup / replication strategy - minimize down time and minimize data loss

Tags: mysql, spring

Just wondering what is the best way to protect data loss in the event of hardware failure?

The goal is to minimize server downtime and minimize data loss.

We cannot afford big-name cloud database vendors, we will have to do it on our dedicated server(s).

I know traditional backup is not sufficient for this, I am thinking about real-time replication.

One thing I am not sure is, if the master failed due to hardware issues, will the replication automatically becomes master? do I need to config anything from my application (Spring boot)?  If the master's hardware issue is fixed, will master automatically sync all data from the replication?  Or there are still manual works?

Can someone please recommend a guide for this?

This is what I am thinking, any comments?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The term you are looking for is high availability cluster (see wikipedia definition: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-availability_cluster) and it is a very broad topic, probably not really suitable for SO. There are lots of ways to create one depending on your exact requirements and available resources. Programming is only a part of it, you need infrastructure and engineering skills / resources as well. My advice: seek professional help if you have not set up one before.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow  I will think about that, but I also want to learn and even if I outsource to someone I still want to understand the architecture :-)

Comment: Again, there is no clear cut, objective answer to the updated question. You are looking for a discussion, expecting comments.